# How to set link area clickable on whole td element?

Tags: html, css

I have some kind of a menu items which consists of links:

```
<tr> 
<td> <a href ="#" onclick="selectItem(this)" style="text-decoration: none">' + response[index] + ' </a> </td> 
</tr>
```

But it is clickable only on some parts of this `<td>` (column). How can i set this to be clickable through the whole column width and height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr> 
   <td onclick="selectItem(this.textContent)" style="cursor:pointer">' + response[index] + ' </td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: I need `this` argument in the function. In your solution it is `undefined`.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle or code snippet. Not sure what you want exactly.

Comment: And what exactly you want to pass to your function? what is `this` for?

Comment: Try to remove anchor tag. leave only `td` with value  `response[index]`. Answer is updated

Comment: It is a simple menu. I need `this` so in `selectItem(argument)` function I can fetch the value `var something = argument.text;`. And this text is fetched from `<a>`

Comment: btw, how you are getting the value? if you are getting undefined then try `this.textContent`

Answer (score 0):

```
  <td style="position: relative;"> 
    <a href ="#" style="text-decoration: none; position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; top: 30%">' + response[index] + ' </a> 
  </td>
```

top: 30% can be adjusted according to the font-size or padding or other css rules that you have.

Comment: It does not work. The width is entitled to text length. So, setting it up as 100% makes no sense.  Ali, hvala u svakom slučaju :).

Comment: :) adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try setting the height and width of anchor tag to 100%.
2. Try event capturing/bubbling in JavaScript (just hint to start).
3. If you are writing this table on your own, try adding on click function on td itself (I am not sure this works or not).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `display: block` for fully fill-in the cell with an `a` element:

```css
table {width: 100%;}
tr {background: blue; border: 1px red solid;}
a.full-link {display: block; background: yellow; text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<table>
<tr> 
<td>
  <a class="full-link" onclick="selectItem(this)" href="">your text </a> 
</td> 
</tr>
</table>
```